# How can i delete "Zero" in date format?

Tags: php

I'm trying to print date.

Example,

```
$firstMonth = "4";
$firstYear = "2013";
for ( $i=0; $i<6; $i++)
{
 $new_date= date( "Ym", mktime(0, 0, 0, $firstMonth-$i, 1, $firstYear) );
 print $new_date."\n";
}
```

Result,

```
201304
201303
201302
201301
201212
201211
```

My requiment is, to print like

```
20134
20133
20132
20131
201212
201211
```

How can i delete the "ZERO" in this situation?

Any good idea?

Comment: for things like this, always check the php.net manual first, there's usually some pointers there :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained in [PHP Date documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php):

> m: Numeric representation of a month, with leading zeros
>
> n: Numeric representation of a month, without leading zeros

So use this format instead:

```
 $new_date= date( "Yn", mktime(0, 0, 0, $firstMonth-$i, 1, $firstYear) );
```